# Create father and child objects in one POST - MVC Core

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

Say I have a `Sale` class:

```
public class Sale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...    
    public ICollection<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
}
```

And an `Item` class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    ...
    public Sale Sale { get; set; }
}
```

And my `view model` looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Sale Sale { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create dynamically the `Items` on `Sales\Create.cshtml`. I tried to do that with `JavaScript,` but on `POST` no items are passed to the `Controller`.

Any doc, ref or advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to build the form field names properly when you're adding new items via JavaScript. Specifically, they'll need to be in the format: `Sale.Items[N].SomeItemProperty`, where `N` is an incremental index.

I'm not sure how you're adding new items dynamically, but this is where libraries like Vue, Knockout, Angular, etc. really help. You manage your items in a JavaScript array and bind that to a templated for loop structure, using the index to dynamically construct the `name` attribute. Then, all you do is just add and remove items from that array and the HTML on the page adjusts accordingly, reindexing all the names.

Comment: The problem that I faced when I tried the incremental index was an argument out of range exception on `Create GET` method, because although `Items` list was initiated, it has no elements. Should I add a “blank” `Item`?

Comment: No. If you're using JavaScript to manage your items, then you should go all the way and not use Razor to render them. Instead, you just pass the data to the view as a JSON object and let your client-side library of choice render both the existing and new items you add. Trying to mix and match is going to confuse your code to the point of being untenable.

Comment: Got it. Working on it right now. Is there any option without JS?

Comment: Not really. When you need to be able to add and remove items, then JS is required. If you were just editing a static list, maybe, but that's almost never the case.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

ItemPartialCreat.cshtml

```
        <div class="add-items">
            <div class="form-inline add-item" data-counter="0">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Items[0].Quantity" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Items[0].Quantity" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Items[0].Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Items[0].Price" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Items[0].Price" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Items[0].Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-remove-item" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove Item">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-add-item" value="Add Item" />            
</div>
```

JS code

```
var wrapper = $('.add-items');

$(".btn-add-item").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var clone = $('.add-item:first-child').clone(true);

    counter = clone.data('counter') + 1;

    clone.attr('data-counter', counter);

    clone.find('[name]').attr('name', function (_, name) {
        return name.replace(/\[\d+\]/, '[' + counter + ']');
    });

    clone.appendTo(wrapper);

    $('.add-item .btn-remove-item').show();
});

$('.btn-remove-item').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.add-item').remove();

    removeButton();
});

function removeButton() {
    if ($('.add-item').length == 1) {
        $('.add-item .btn-remove-item').hide();
    }
}
```